# How to make an input search form to take data from users in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, active-form, yii2-widget

I need to make a search-form in the front-end to take input from users and search for it in the database, then display the data depending on that keyword.
I need to use yii2 active form not HTML form.
If any code example for the search-form, the action in site controller, and the view, it would be grate.

Thanks

Comment: do you want see the result of the query in gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic one :)

SiteController.php (controller file):

```
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use Yii;

class SiteController extends yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionSearch() {
        $searchString = Yii::$app->request->get('query');
        $searchQuery = Product::find()->where(['name' => $searchString])->orderBy(['ts' => SORT_DESC]);
        $productDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $searchQuery]);

    return $this->render('search', compact('productDataProvider'));
}
```

search.php (view file):

```
<?php 
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\grid\GridView;

$form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin([
        'options' => ['role' => 'form', 'method' => 'GET', 'action' => Url::to(['site/search'])]
    ]); ?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'query')?>

    <?=\yii\helpers\Html::submitButton('Поиск')?>

<?php $form->end()?>

<? if ($productDataProvider->totalCount): ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $productDataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            'name'
        ],
    ]) ?>
<? else: ?>
    <p>Ничего не найдено</p>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @hutsi, but it didn't work.
I solved the problem. thanks again